# escapar caracteres especiales en conexión pdo odbc sybase

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, sybase

Me estoy conectando a una base de datos sybase mediante odbc sin problemas con la siguiente conexion:

```
$db = "odbc:my_db";
$con = new PDO($db, "$user", "$pass");
```

pero cuando alguno de los campos de la base de datos tiene acentos o ñ o caracteres especiales me muestra iconos raros como �.
No tengo acceso a la configuración de la base de datos.

Ya intente lo siguiente pero me marca error:

```
$con = new PDO($db, "$user", "$pass", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Ayuda!

Comment: Qué usas para conectarte? FreeTDS?

Comment: no, solo con el Administrador de origen de datos ODBC (32 bits) de windows

Answer (score 0):

Yo manejo mis conexiones de la siguiente forma y me funciona de maravilla:

```
$mbd = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST; dbname=DB;', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES  'UTF8'"));
```